# JPA Secondary table joining on wrong columns

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm doing a server-client project which is supposed to be like a Cinema site. I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL database.

This is Movie Table

[image]

and this is Showings Table

[image]

And I have a class on my server that looks like this

```
package pwsztar.edu.pl.project_kino.dto;

import org.hibernate.annotations.ManyToAny;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.BooleanArrayType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;

@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(
                name = "boolean-array",
                typeClass = BooleanArrayType.class
        )
})
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(schema = "kino" ,name ="film", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "idf"))
@Table(name = "seans",schema = "kino")
public class Seans{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id_se;
    private int id_sali;
    private int cena_zwykly;
    private int cena_vip;
    private int idf;
    private LocalDate dzien;
    private Time godzina;

    @Type(type = "boolean-array")
    @Column(name = "miejsca_zwykle",columnDefinition = "boolean[]" )
    private Boolean[] miejsca_zwykle;

    @Type(type = "boolean-array")
    @Column(name = "miejsca_vip",columnDefinition = "boolean[]")
    private Boolean[] miejsca_vip;

    @Column (name = "tytul",table = "film")
    private String tytul;

    @Column (name ="zdjecie",table = "film")
    private String zdjecie;
```

The **id_se** in "Seans" table is the showing the ID and **idf** in "Film" table is the movie ID. When I try to print out all the showings, it is supposed to print out all the showing data + the tittle and the link to the example picture of the movie but instead i get nulls there. I think that JPA does the JOIN on the wrong tables, if set the primmary key of "Seans" class to be "idf" it would work, but i can't. What am I supposed to do for this to work.

PS: Sorry for not english names of the variables and column names.

Edit: It work's for the first 12 showings, but it's probably because that's the amount of movies that it in data base. The Join is probably seans.id_se = film.idf

[image]

Comment: do you have seans without films? if you do have, it is correct to have null values for film members

Comment: @tremendous7 I do not